# Rotating a polygon about origin

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm trying to rotate an object (set of vertices) about the origin in opengl.

The object being a Carriage in a Ferris wheel which must not must stay upright during the rotation. So far all I've got is the following transformation which rotates the carriage but does not stay upright. This uses basic rotation transformation about the origin at a 72 degree angle. The model martix looks something like this:

```
g_modelMatrix[i] = glm::mat4(1.0f) * glm::rotate(glm::radians(-72.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
```

where glm::mat4(1.0f)is an identity matrix

The end result transforms the carriage but does not make it upright. 
[image]
What transformation would be appropriate for this kind of problem?

Comment: Rotate the carriage the opposite way before translating it?

Comment: Do you mean rotating anti clockwise (72deg) then translating (x,y) to get it back to the original position, then again rotate  clockwise (72deg )?

Comment: Yes, I do mean that.

Comment: But how do I figure out x and y , for every transformation?

Comment: If the centre of the wheel is not at the origin, then first translate the wheel to the origin, then rotate, then translate back. This will apply only to the wheel; the rest of objects need a different view-matrix ( another rendering call).

Comment: Given I have a different view-matrix for the carriage, What would the transformation look like?

Comment: Don't rotate them at all. Calculate the positions and apply translation only.

Comment: Yea makes sense, but having troubles calculating the translation x and y distances. Only information I can use is the radius of the circle.

Comment: If you use @immibis' approach, you don't need to care about the actual position. The transform would be `rotate(i * 72°) * translate(r, 0, 0) * rotate(-i * 72°)` or similar.

Comment: Yep that worked. If one of you could write it as the answer, I could mark it as correct. Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the approach I used to solve the problem.

```
rotate(i * 72°) * translate(r, 0, 0) * rotate(-i * 72°)
```